# I want to match a newline character followed by a string using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

```
Device ID: xyz
Entry address(es): 
 IP address: 10.3.10.46
Platform: WS-x,  Capabilities: Switch IGMP 
Interface: GigabitEthernet9/33,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
Holdtime : 177 sec
Management address(es): 
 IP address: 10.3.10.46
```

above is a snipet from a file.From among the above i want to collect the ip address by matching only the 2 lines below.
Entry address(es): 
 IP address: 10.3.10.46
or
Management address(es): 
 IP address: 10.3.10.46

The regular expression i have written is as follows which does not work and i am not able to resolve how i can show the **new line** after "address(es):" in my regular expression.

```
f = open(fileName)
for line in f:
    matchObj1 = re.match(r'Entry address\(es\):\s+IP address: ([0-9.]+)', line)
    if matchObj1:
    print "IP Address = ", matchObj1.group(1)

    matchObj2 = re.match(r'Entry address\(es\):\s+IP address: ([0-9.]+)', line)
    if matchObj2:
    print "IP Address = ", matchObj2.group(1)
```

Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions for this. Your input looks like the output of a configuration file or a program, and easy to parse.

```
def get_addresses(fname):
    addresses = {}
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = [l.strip().lower() for l in f]

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("ip address"):
            ip = line.split(": ")[1]
            address_type = lines[i-1]
            if address_type == "entry address(es):":
                addresses["entry"] = ip
            elif address_type == "management address(es):":
                addresses["management"] = ip
            # Add additional address type handling here

    return addresses
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but the problem comes when i have "Entry address(es): " followed by IP address and also "Management address(es): " followed by IP address which is also in the same format. So what i am looking for, is to match the 2 lines using regular expression separated by '\n'

Comment: You still don't need a regex to do that (take a look at my edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`, `re.match` is used for matching from the start of string:

```
>>> s = 'Device ID: xyz\nEntry address(es): \n      IP address: 10.3.10.46\n    Platform: WS-x,  Capabilities: Switch IGMP \n    Interface: GigabitEthernet9/33,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2\n    Holdtime : 177 sec'
>>> re.search(r'Entry address\(es\):\s+IP address: ([0-9.]+)', s).group(1)
'10.3.10.46'
```

[`search()` vs. `match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string,
>   while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string.